# Why is text mode scrolling slow?

Tags: terminal, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

In any text mode, from the GRUB menu loading, through booting, and also in any VT other than the one where X is running, text scrolling is abysmally slow (several seconds for a dense screenful of text). Is it possible that I need to install/enable VESA or some other driver in addition to the [nvidia](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA) one I'm using already for these modes to work properly? And could it be related to the following error message from `journalctl`:

> kernel: NVRM: Your system is not currently configured to drive a VGA console on the primary VGA device. The NVIDIA Linux graphics driver requires the use of a text-mode VGA console. Use of other console drivers including, but not limited to, vesafb, may result in corruption and stability problems, and is not supported.

I've tried [adding the `nvidia` module to the ramdisk](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1352833#p1352833) and [setting `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/480159).

Update: After [switching to the Nouveau driver](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#Switching_between_NVIDIA_and_nouveau_drivers) everything *after* the GRUB menu is fast, but not the GRUB menu itself. Much less of an issue, but would be nice to know why it's slow to start with.

---

This is also an issue on a new HiDPI laptop with Intel HD Graphics 520 - GRUB is slow, boot menu is slow, but once I'm in a window manager `xterm`+`bash` is super fast.

Comment: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/827139/uefi-nvidia-vga-console-complaints-/